# SailsJS | TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, sails.js, q

I get this error when I 'GET' this controller action:

> **TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined**

Code:

```
allUsers: function (req, res) {
    Admin.find({ id: req.adminId }, function (err, admin) {
      console.log(admin);
    })
    .then(function onSuccess(admin) {
      return User.find(function (err, users) {
        res.json(users);
      });
    })
    .catch(function onError(res) {
      return res.status(401).send();
    });
  }
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You should not pass callbacks to functions other than `then` and `catch` if you want to use promises?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to mix callback and promise style here.
What happens if you delete the part:

```
, function (err, admin) {
    console.log(admin);
}
```

According to [Sails.js ORM documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/queries), the promise style `find` is crafted like this:

```
Zookeeper.find()
.then(function (zookeepers) {...})
.catch(function (err) {...});
```

Comment: Thanks. Refactoring now. I will let you know!

Comment: Worked like a charm! XD Thank you!